# org.json.JSONException: No value for data (for a simple app with a button)

Tags: java, android, json

Happy new year !!! I am trying to make a button that display a TextView with a character from json file. But I get JSONException No value for data. I am new to working on JSON in java. Can you please help me where is the issue? Thank You.

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pirama4.pirama4;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private int currentIndex=0;


    public void loadGrades1(View view){
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc);
        currentIndex++;
        String s = list.get(currentIndex);
        txt.setText(s);
    }

    private void parseJson(String s){
        TextView mala = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc);
        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray dt = root.getJSONArray("data");
            int len = dt.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                JSONObject chara = dt.getJSONObject(i);
                s = chara.optString("character", "");
                if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                    list.add(s);
                }
            }
            mala.setText(list.get(1));
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadGrades(View view){
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream is= res.openRawResource(R.raw.test02);;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
        }

        parseJson(builder.toString());
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

#### A sample of my json

```
{"data":[
{"character":"a",
"pronunciation":"A"
},
{
"character":"b",
"pronunciation":"B"
}
]
}
```

#### My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.pirama4.pirama4.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press me"
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="loadGrades"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press after press me"
        android:id="@+id/abcc"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="loadGrades1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/acc"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Logcat Errors

```
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for data
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at com.example.pirama4.pirama4.MainActivity.parseJson(MainActivity.java:33)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at com.example.pirama4.pirama4.MainActivity.loadGrades(MainActivity.java:58)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
01-01 16:46:15.366 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
01-01 16:46:15.368 15585-15585/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-01 16:46:17.186 15585-15601/com.example.pirama4.pirama4 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x76f9165b3060: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x76f9165bba20)
```

Comment: Is the json valid?

Comment: JSON isn't valid.

Comment: json is fine I have tested in python

Comment: Are you sure ?? did you pasted exact JSON here ?? Don't say yes, before cross verifying it again. Tell me, how on earth `"pronunciation:"A"` is valid ???

Comment: I edited it.This is a sample of my json file .The json file which I use in my computer is fine I tested with a similar program in python.Python checks if a json file is valid and throw error if it is not.

Comment: @SmithTrigger So, you are accepting, it wasn't correct. right ?  Now, did you tested with latest change ?

Comment: The json file which I use is 3999 characters is too big for stackoverflow and is valid because it is work fine in python.Python language checks if a json file is valid

Comment: @SmithTrigger :: It appears as if the Json data in your resource file is either not structured as you have shown in your post or the data is somehow corrupt. Try the code I posted and see what happens and how the Json data is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting closer to the solution for your project, but you are still loading the data each time you click the `Button`.

From your error message it appears as if the data you are returning is empty and `JSONObject` does not play well with empty strings.

Do this:

```
private static final TAG = "TheNameOfYourActivity";

private void loadDataFromResourceFile(){
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream is= res.openRawResource(R.raw.test02);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        builder.append(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    String result = builder.toString();
    if(!result.isEmpty()){
        parseJson(result);
        // Just show the first 250 characters of the string!! 3999 "character" elements is quite a bit
        Log.e(TAG, "The contents of my resource file = "  + result.substring(0,250));
    }
    else{
        Log.e(TAG, "My resource file  is empty");
    }
}
```

In your `onCreate` method load the data and get the instance of your `TextView`:

```
private TextView mTvAcc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // you only need to do this once since we are making the object a instance variable!
    mTvAcc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acc);

    // With this we load the data when the Activity is created 
    // This happens only once -- But with a large resource file you might want to 
    // do load the data in an AsyncTask (more advanced)
    loadDataFromResourceFile();
}
```

A bit of an error in your `parseJson` method. The `ArrayList` "list has not been initialized and since we now have the `TextView` object as an instance variable we can get rid if the unneeded "mala" object.

```
private void parseJson(String jsonString){
    // now we initialize the ArrayList
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray dt = root.getJSONArray("data");
        int len = dt.length();

        // Check the length of the JSONArray object!
        Log.e(TAG, "Number of data objects = " + len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            JSONObject chara = dt.getJSONObject(i);
            String s = chara.optString("character", "");
            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
        // The first value in the ArrayList start with the index value 0!!
        currentIndex = 0;
        String sText = list.get(currentIndex)
        Log.e(TAG, "First Value = " + sText);
        mTvAcc.setText(sText);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e(TAG, getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now get rid of "loadGrades" method and rename the "loadGrades1" method and implement like this:

```
public void loadGrades(View view){
    currentIndex++;
    String s = list.get(currentIndex);
    mTvAcc.setText(s);
}
```

And you can get rid of this, too:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="press after press me"
        android:id="@+id/abcc"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="loadGrades1"/>
```

Now if everything has gone well and the data was read successfully you should see the first text in the `TextView`.

**Disclaimer**:: I did this in a text editor, so there may be a couple of misspellings of methods or syntax errors.

Comment: Is the same in loadGrades the currentIndex with the currentIndex in parseJson ?

Comment: Json file has 3999 "character" elements

Comment: The flow of your program should basically be :: `onCreate` calls "loadDataFromResourceFile" and reads your resource file (?This returns what you expect?). If the returned string is NOT empty "parseJson" will be called and the JSONArray object "data"  will be looped through and all the values in your "character" field will be added to the `ArrayList` "list". You set the text in your `TextView` "mTvAcc" to the first value (index=0) in "list". You maintain a reference to the current index value and increment that each time the button is clicked.

Comment: @SmithTrigger :: Take a look at my answer again. I have add a couple of `Log` requests. (1) inside the "loadDataFromResourceFile"  method. Do you see the expected JSON string??   (2) inside the "parseJson" method just before the `for` loop. Do you get the expected number of data ??  (3) inside "parseJson"  just after the `for` loop the logcat should show "First Value = a" ??  (4) inside the `catch` clause there is a `Log.e(TAG, getMessage());` is it being triggered?? Please go through this list and see what you get.